# Strange result when adding one year to java.util.Calendar

Tags: java, date, kotlin

Initialize `java.util.Calendar` with `May, 31 1900`. Then add one year to it twenty times.

Here's code:

```
import java.text.DateFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

fun main(args : Array<String>) {
    val f = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.dd.MM")
    val cal = Calendar.getInstance()
    cal.set(1900, Calendar.MAY, 31)
    for(i in 1..20) {
        println(f.format(cal.time))
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1)
    }
}
```

The output is following:

```
1900.31.05
1901.31.05
1902.31.05
1903.31.05
1904.31.05
1905.31.05
1906.31.05
1907.31.05
1908.31.05
1909.31.05
1910.31.05
1911.31.05
1912.31.05
1913.31.05
1914.31.05
1915.31.05
1916.31.05
1917.31.05
1918.01.06
1919.01.06
```

Why I get June, 1 instead of May, 31 since 1918?

UPD: with time information

```
1917.31.05 23:38:50.611
1918.01.06 01:38:50.611
```

If this is DST invention, how do I prevent that?

Comment: The invention of DST, probably. Print the entire thing, including time information.

Comment: No, I don't think this has to do with Shanghai

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yeah, I retracted already ;)

Comment: weird i don't reproduce this, might have something to do with your timezone ?

Comment: Why not use another DateTime?

Comment: If you want to work with dates only then it's better to use `java.time.LocalDate` - this is really a date, whereas `java.util.Calendar` works with a timestamp (date and time)

Comment: [This](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/russia/moscow?year=1918) may be the reason.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: The Gregorian calendar was implemented in Russia on 14 February 1918 by dropping the Julian dates of 1–13 February 1918 pursuant to a Sovnarkom decree signed 24 January 1918 (Julian) by Vladimir Lenin. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soviet_calendar

Comment: @SlavaGlushenkov I suggest you make your comment into an Answer, perhaps with a code example as proof.

Comment: Interesting piece of info, @SlavaGlushenkov, but could that affect a date in May that year? I don’t see how.

Comment: “If this is DST invention, how do I prevent that?” I’m afraid it’s much too late to prevent DST invention. :-(

Comment: Well spotted, @Turing85. According to my investigation, Europe(Moscow is the only time zone that can explain. Do you want to turn your comment into an answer? (No pressure)

Comment: @OleV.V. Nah, the answer would most probably only contain the link =)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You seem to be running your code in a timezone that changed its offset by two hours in 1917 or 1918.  That is, the number of hours ahead or behind UTC changed.  I've no idea why your timezone would have done that, but I'm sure there's a good historical reason for it.

If you're only interested in dates, without the Time component, use the `java.time.LocalDate` class, which effectively represents a day, month and year only.  It's not subject to any daylight savings anomalies.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
```

or

```
LocalDate moonLanding = LocalDate.of(1969, 7, 20);
```

Comment: A change in 1917 or 1918 isn’t in itself enough to explain. The likely explanation is a transition where the clock is moved forward on May 31, 1918, so that the clock hour that we would hit by adding a year doesn’t exist. The the `Calendar` picks another time, and in this case a time past midnight, so the date is June 1 instead.

Comment: Yes, @OleV.V you are right.  And according to the link provided by Turing85, that's exactly what happened.  On that particular day, the clock was moved from 10pm to midnight.  Ole, If you would like to write your own answer, then ping me, I shall upvote you.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming that you are in Europe/Moscow time zone. Turing85 in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49929791/strange-result-when-adding-one-year-to-java-util-calendar#comment86875949_49929791) correctly spotted the cause of the behaviour you observed: In 1918 summer time (DST) in your time zone began on May 31. The clock was moved forward from 22:00 to 24:00, that is, by two hours. Your `Calendar` object is aware of this and therefore refuses to give 23:38:50.611 on this date. Instead it picks the time 2 hours later, 1918.01.06 01:38:50.611. Now the month and day-of-month have changed to 1st of June.

Unfortunately this change is kept in the `Calendar` and carried on to the following year.

> If this is DST invention, how do I prevent that?

Thomas Kläger in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49929791/strange-result-when-adding-one-year-to-java-util-calendar#comment86875911_49929791) gave the right solution: If you only need the dates, use `LocalDate` from `java.time`:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu.dd.MM");
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(1900, Month.MAY, 31);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        System.out.println(date.format(dateFormatter));
        date = date.plusYears(1);
    }
```

Output (abbreviated):

```
1900.31.05
1901.31.05
…
1917.31.05
1918.31.05
1919.31.05
```

The “local” in `LocalDate` means “without timezone” in `java.time` jargon, so this is guaranteed to keep you free of surprises from time zone anomalies.

If you need a time, you may consider `LocalDateTime`, but since this is without time zone too, it *will* give you the non-existing time of 1918.31.05 23:38:50.611, so maybe not.

An alternative thing you may consider is adding the right number of years to your origin of 1900.31.05 23:38:50.611. Then at least you will only have surprises in years where you hit a non-existing time. I am using `ZonedDateTime` for this demonstration:

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu.dd.MM HH:mm:ss.SSS");
    ZonedDateTime originalDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(1900, Month.MAY.getValue(), 31,
            23, 30, 50, 611000000, ZoneId.of("Europe/Moscow"));
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        System.out.println(originalDateTime.plusYears(i).format(formatter));
    }
```

Output:

```
1900.31.05 23:30:50.611
1901.31.05 23:30:50.611
…
1917.31.05 23:30:50.611
1918.01.06 01:30:50.611
1919.01.06 00:30:50.611
1920.31.05 23:30:50.611
…
1924.31.05 23:30:50.611
```

Again in 1919 summer time began on May 31. This time the clock was only advanced by 1 hour, from 23 to 24, so you get only 1 hour later than the imaginary time of 23:30:50.611.

I am recommending `java.time` for date and time work, not least when doing math on dates like you do. The `Calendar` class is considered long outmoded. `java.time` was designed acknowledging that `Calendar` and the other old classes were poorly designed. The modern ones are so much nicer to work with.

### How could I be sure it was Moscow?

In no other time zone than Europe/Moscow is the time of 1918.31.05 23:38:50.611 nonexistent. I checked:

```
    LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.of(1918, Month.MAY, 31, 23, 38, 50, 611000000);
    for (String zid : ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()) {
        ZonedDateTime zdt = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of(zid));
        LocalDateTime newDateTime = zdt.toLocalDateTime();
        if (! newDateTime.equals(dateTime)) {
            System.out.println(zid + ": -> " + zdt + " -> " + newDateTime);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Europe/Moscow: -> 1918-06-01T01:38:50.611+04:31:19[Europe/Moscow] -> 1918-06-01T01:38:50.611
W-SU: -> 1918-06-01T01:38:50.611+04:31:19[W-SU] -> 1918-06-01T01:38:50.611
```

“W-SU” is a deprecated name for the same time zone, it stands for Western Soviet Union.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Time Changes in Moscow Over the Years](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/russia/moscow?year=1918)
- [List of tz database time zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) showing W-SU as deprecated.
- [An old message on an IANA mailing list](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2006-May/013582.html) stating “But long ago … we based the name on some more-political entity than a city name.  For example, we used "W-SU" for the western Soviet Union…”